# Matlab code to charge to a maximum value of capacity

Tags: matlab, loops, max, min

I want to get rCl, which is remaining charge of a battery in an e-vehicle. Currently the values are wrong as I am not getting the code right.

rCl should be a max of 1000. nCl describes the amount (in kWh) it is using, and pCp the amount (in kWh), it could potentially load. So it should be like that:

```
rCl(x) = rCl(x-1) -nCl(x-1) + pCp(x-1) --> to a a max of 1000kWh
```

I tried several things, including this:

```
for x = 2:2:2734
Cp(x) = min(nC(x-1),pCp(x))
end

for x = 2:1:2734
rC(x) = rC(x-1) - nC(x-1) + Cp(x-1)
end
```

But I just cant figure it out - I might have been looking at it for to long already... any suggestions are welcome!

If you look at the pic of the data, you may notice, it works as long as pCp is greater than nCl and therefor it can load to full. Once this is not working anymore, the load never goes to full again and keeps on decreasing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
for x = 2:1:tablesize
rCl(x) = rCl(x-1)-nCl(x-1)+pCp(x-1)
if rCl(x) > 1000
rCl(x) = 1000
end
end
```